# Error: /directory/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nodejs

I kept on getting an error after I was trying to start a Javascript file

```
Error: /directory/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header
```

is there a way I could fix this issue

Node: 16.15.1

Comment: This is NOT the whole message and the important parts are missing. Short generic version: Install the correct version for what the error creates: the error refers to using a wrong architecture (so when on amd64 trying something that is for arm or i386). Deploying a node to another machine does NOT fix architectural dependencies.

Comment: see http://dustinbolton.com/invalid-elf-header-running-a-nodejs-script-on-raspberry-pi/ and   https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1000 and https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had to add node_modules to the .dockerignore file

Answer (score 0):

When the `node_modules` folder is not added to `.dockerignore`, all files in that folder are also included in the build context, and Docker tries to re-install dependencies, including binary modules, when npm install is run inside the container. However, binaries built on the local machine may not be compatible with the Docker container, resulting in an invalid ELF header error.

Adding `node_modules` to `.dockerignore` allows Docker not to include this folder in the build context and to use the dependencies installed on the local machine, including correctly built modules.

To add node_modules to .dockerignore, create a .dockerignore file in the same directory as your Dockerfile and add the following line:

```
node_modules
```